# Linux test command with sed is not working

Tags: linux, sed

Here is my code which always returns 'false' only:-

```
export STR="MYC-14:: This is sample string only."
echo $STR
test -z "$(echo "$STR" |  sed '/^MYC-/p' )" && echo "true" || echo "false"
```

I'm trying to match the starting characters "**MYC-**" from the variable called "**STR**" but seems like the regular expression within `sed` condition is wrong due to which test command is returning false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I'm able to make it work:-

```
export STR="MYC-14:: This is sample string only."
echo $STR

test -z "$(echo "$STR" |  sed '/^MYC-/d' )" && echo "truee" || echo "falsee"
```

Comment: Sadly, this will also echo `truee` if `STR` is the empty string.  You want `test -n`

Answer (score 2):

`test -z "$str"` succeeds (returns 0) when `$str` is the empty string.  Your `sed` command is outputting data, so the string is not empty and `test` is failing (returning non-zero).  So the `echo "false"` branch is executed.

Note that `test` is not "returning false".  It is returning non-zero (eg, it is failing).  `if` does not test boolean conditions, and it is better if you stop thinking about true/false and instead think about success/failure.  `test` failed, because the string it tested was not empty.  Because `sed` generated some output.

If you want to test that a string is not the empty string, use `test -n`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `sed` always outputs the line after processing. Therefore,

```
echo "$STR" |  sed '/^MYC-/p'
```

will always output the line: once if it doesn't match, twice if it matches.

Use `sed -n` to tell sed **not to print** the line by default.

Most shells make it possible to test this without running an external tool. For example, in bash you can write

```
if [[ $STR = MYC-* ]] ; then
    ...
fi
```